# For which values of $a$ and $b$ is the integral convergent?

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals

I have to find the values $a, b > 0$ that makes the following integral convergent:

$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^a(1+x^b)} \,dx$

I've tried integrating $\frac{1}{x^a(1+x^b)}$ by plugging in different values of $a$ and $b$, and found out that the value of $a$ doesn't matter (I am not too sure if this is right) and $b \leq 1$ for the integral to be convergent, but I am not sure how I can justify this. Can someone help me?

Comment: @Arthur: fixed, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Compare with $\int_1^{\infty} \frac 1 {x^{a+b}}dx$. It is convegent iff $a+b>1$.

$\frac 1 {2(x^{a+b})}\leq \frac 1 {x^{a}(1+x^{b})} \leq \frac 1 {x^{a+b}}$ for all $x \in (1,\infty)$.

Comment: Is there any other method where I can evaluate the values $a$ and $b$ separately rather than just knowing $a + b > 1$?

Comment: @abrakadabra_01 Intuitively, the convergence is in question only for $x$ near $\infty$. The constant term $1$ in the denominator has no effect on convergence since the dominating term in $1+x^{b}$ is $x^{b}$. That is the reason I comparted the given integral with that of $\frac 1 {x^{a+b}}$.

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question. If the integral was $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^a(1+x^b)} \,dx$ rather than $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^a(1+x^b)} \,dx$, i.e. the lower bound of the integral is changed from 1 to 0, would the conditions differ?

Comment: @abrakadabra_01 Certainly. In that case integrability near $0$ depends on the value of $a$. In that case you get two conditioins: $a+b >1$ and $a <1$.

Comment: Could you explain a bit further what you mean by "integrability near 0 demands on the value of a"? Thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: You can split the integral into integral form $0$ to $1$ and  the integral form $1$ to $\infty$. For the integral from $0$ to $1$ note that $\frac 1{x^{a}(1+x^{b})}$ lies between $\frac 1{x^{a}}$ and $\frac 1{2x^{a}}$. And the integral of $\frac 1{x^{a}}$  can be computed explicitly as $x^{1-a}|_0^{1}$ which is finite iff $a <1$. @abrakadabra_01